# Snapshot of whole stage (with titlebar, borders, etc.)

Tags: javafx-8

Is there a way to make a snapshot of entire Stage (or Window in general) with decoration (titlebar, border, etc.) in JavaFX? I know that I can make a snapshot of a Scene, but it would not contain window decotation.

[EDIT]

I need to take a snapshot of stage even if it is not visible (is hidden behind another window). So using `java.awt.Robot.createScreenCapture(..)` is not suitable.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the Robot  [createScreenCapture](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html#createScreenCapture-java.awt.Rectangle-) class to do it als Scene.snapshot only captures the scene itself.

```
Rectangle screenRect = new Rectangle(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize());
BufferedImage capture = new Robot().createScreenCapture(screenRect);
ImageIO.write(capture, "bmp", new File(args[0]));
```

Comment: Thanks, but `new Robot.createScreenCapture(..)` will take snapshot of what is visible on the screen. And when my application is hidden behind another application, that other application will end up in snapshot. And this is not what I need.

Comment: This wasn't part of your original question. You're only option is to only get the stage **without** the window decoration then.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of code, you have to make a `BufferedImage` and then convert it to a `WriteableImage`. There may be an easier way to do this, but to get the window, this is the way I do it:

**NOTE:** To get the stage, use the following code (you can use any `fx:id` you have defined; doesn't have to be the `AnchorPane`).

```
@FXML private AnchorPane ap;
Stage stage = (Stage) ap.getScene().getWindow();

File file = new File("snapshot.png");

try {

    Rectangle rectangle = new Rectangle((int)stage.getX(), (int)stage.getY(),
        (int)stage.getWidth(), (int)stage.getHeight());

    BufferedImage bufferedImage = new Robot().createScreenCapture(rectangle);

    ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", file);

} catch (IOException ex) {
    //IOException
} catch (AWTException ex) {
    //AWTException
}
```

Also, be sure to be using the `java.awt.Rectangle` and not the javafx one.

Comment: Thanks, but `new Robot.createScreenCapture(..)` is not suitable for me. Look at my comment for @Inge answear.

Comment: @Robert Why don't you just call ImageIO.write(bufferedImage, "png", file); ? The conversion to a WritableImage seems to be completely unnecessary here.

Comment: @mipa I didn't know I could write the bufferedImage directly to it. Code update to reflect this :)